# "arules" library's "read.transaction()" reads in CSV files with an additional, blank column for every transaction

Tags: r, csv, arules

When you attempt to read CSV files that aren't the default groceries.csv, every transaction has an additional entry in it — a blank space — which will mess up all of the calculations for analysis (and even crash R if your CSV file is big enough). I've tried to insert NA's into all of the blank cells in my CSV file, but I cannot find a way to remove all of them within the read.transactions() command (remove duplicates leaves a single NA). I haven't found a trustworthy way to fix this in any of the other questions on stackoverflow, nor anywhere else on the internet.

Example entry:

```
> inspect(trans[1:5])
  items                       
1 {,                          
   FACEBOOK.COM,              
   Google,                    
   Google Web Search}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say. I assume you read the data with `read.transactions()`. Does your CSV file have leading white spaces in some/all lines? You could try to use the `cols` parameter in `read.transactions()` to fix the problem.

An example with data and the code to replicate the problem would help.

Comment: I just figures out that your problem is most likely that your CSV file has trailing commas. The code in the upcoming release (1.1-10) will resolve the issues in `read.transaction()` with leading and trailing white spaces and trailing commas in the csv file.